# Assigning multiple records generated via string parsing to a VBA array

Tags: arrays, string, vba

A line in my text file is in the following format:

**length of field** : value

Example:

"**006**:170000,**004**:0002,**009**:000358827,**009**:003628325,**005**:71001,**002**:71,**004**:0000,**000**:,**005**:95.16,**010**:1000000.00" ... (length can be much longer)

*The value can also have a comma

I am currently exporting this data in such a way that inside a loop I retrieve the first value and after that I assign this value to a predefined temporary array. This process (string parsing) is repeated until I reach the end of the string. But I find this is slow for large files. What would be a faster way to assign the values I get via parsing of the string to my array?

Comment: MyArray = Split(MyString,",")

Comment: I think this would be a good way, but there is a possibility that a value also has a comma.

Comment: @Brother0 if your array will contain all sorts of wild chards such as `;` or `,` then you won't be able to split the string into array elements. Do you have some kind of marker ?

Comment: Basically the problem is that the values are not seperated by any character but their position in the string. The first four chars in the string describe the poistion of the first value, the position of the next value is then described in the 4 chars that follow. Maybe a solution with regular expression exists for my problem?

Comment: I found a solution via the following regular expression ",?[0-9]{3}:", after that I will use the method by Stai. Thank you for your help Stai and Shai Rado, as I have some control over the data (I am exporing data from an ERP system) I'think I'll be able to avoid problems that could occur as the method used depends on some assumptions (text values with the pattern of the regular expression would break the method).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have an empty value in your example string `000:,`.

You can split the values by the colon and then trim the last 4 characters off of each element in the array.  I emptied the first element in the array because it contains a key not a value.

```
Sub ArrayUsingSplit()
   Const StringValues = "006:170000,004:0002,009:000358827,009:003628325,005:71001,002:71,004:0000,000:,005:95.16,010:1000000.00"
   Dim arrValues
   Dim x As Long

   arrValues = Split(StringValues, ":")

   arrValues(0) = ""

   For x = 1 To UBound(arrValues)
        arrValues(x) = Left(arrValues(x), Len(arrValues(x)) - 4)
   Next

   Debug.Print Join(arrValues, "~")
End Sub
```

Is this what you are doing?

```
Sub ArrayUsingMid()
    Const StringValues = "006:170000,004:0002,009:000358827,009:003628325,005:71001,002:71,004:0000,000:,005:95.16,010:1000000.00"
    Dim i As Long, iStart As Integer, iEnd As Integer, iLength

    Dim arrValues()

    iEnd = 1

    Do
        ReDim Preserve arrValues(i)

        iStart = InStr(iEnd, StringValues, ":") + 1
        iEnd = InStr(iStart, StringValues, ":")
        iLength = iEnd - iStart - 4

        If iEnd > 0 Then
            arrValues(i) = Mid(StringValues, iStart, iLength)
        Else
            arrValues(i) = Mid(StringValues, iStart)
        End If

        i = i + 1
    Loop Until iEnd = 0


    Debug.Print Join(arrValues, "~")

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bit shorter with `Evaluate`. For example `a = [{001,0;005,01.23}]` will generate 2 dimensional array with the values `( 1, 0 ) , ( 5 , 1.23 )`. The code can be something like

```
s = "006:170000,004:0002,009:000358827,009:003628325,005:71001,002:71,004:0000,000:"

s = Replace(s, ",", ";")
s = Replace(s, ":", ",0") ' ",0 because Evaluate doesn't allow blank values like "{1,}"

a = Evaluate("{" & s & "}")     ' ( 6, 170000 ), ( 4, 2 ), ( 9, 358827 ), ...
```

If you want to keep the leading zeros, you can keep them as strings:

```
s = "006:170000,004:0002,009:000358827,009:003628325,005:71001,002:71,004:0000,000:"

s = Replace(s, ",", """;""")
s = Replace(s, ":", """,""")
s = "{""" & s & """}"

a = Evaluate(s)       ' ( "006", "170000" ), ( "004", "0002" ), ...
```